# Count maximum inversions for k subarrays

Tags: arrays, algorithm, dynamic-programming

I have this problem:

> Given an array `A` and an integer `K`, partition `A` into `K` contiguous subarrays in the way that maximizes the sum of the number of inversions in each subarray. (An "inversion" is a pair of indices `i`, `j` where `i < j` and `A[i] > A[j]`.)
>
> Return the sum.
>
> For example, if `A = 9 1 7 2 3` and `K = 2`, then the answer is `4`, because you can split the array into `9 1 7 2` (which has four inversions) and `3` (which has none), and 4 + 0 = 4.
>
> **Constaints**
>
> ```
> 1 <= A.size <= 500
> 1 <= k <= A.size
> 1 <= A[i] <= 100000
> ```

My thoughts:

- This looks like a dynamic programming problem but I can't work out how to integrate `K` groups into the solution.
- This problems roughly translates to finding `K` groups with each group having the highest number of increasing elements within that group.

Any ideas on how to solve this would be helpful.

Comment: can you tell a bit more why do you think this is a DP problem? I can see memoization but where is overlapping sub problems?

Comment: I don't see how you get four inversions in `1, 7, 2, 3`. And don't you mean "highest number of *decreasing* elements"?

Comment: "inversions in each of the group is the maximum" is unclear. Please clarify if you are looking to maximize the total number of inversions in all groups combined or something else.

Comment: What are the highest `length(A)` and `K` can be?

Answer (score 2):

We can at least have an `O(n^2 * k)` dynamic program. Let `f(i, k)` represent the most inversions up to index `i` with `k` groups. Then:

```
f(i, k) = max(
  inversion_count(j, i) + f(j - 1, k - 1)
)
for k <= j <= i
```

We can precalculate a step to make the result for `inversion_count(interval)` `O(1)` time by using `O(n^2)` time and space: for all elements, `e`, in `A`, store how many smaller elements are in each interval that starts at `e`. When we decrease `j` in the main iteration, increasing the size of the interval, the number of inversions increases by the number of elements smaller than `A[j]` in the interval `[j, i]`, which we've precalculated.